# Run Kubernetes as Windows Service

Tags: windows-server-2016

On Windows I am starting Kubernetes using the `start.ps1` [script](https://github.com/Microsoft/SDN/tree/master/Kubernetes/flannel/l2bridge). This is a manual step that opens multiple powershell windows that need to be kept open. I am looking for a way to register the Kubernetes components as a Windows service, so they get started automatically after a reboot.

I am running Windows Server Core so I need a solution that works with powershell.

Comment: Is this not what you're looking for? https://github.com/Microsoft/SDN/tree/master/Kubernetes/flannel/l2bridge#5-deploy-an-example-windows-service-make-sure-container-image-matches-host-os

Comment: You might try [Minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube) as described in [this article](https://rominirani.com/tutorial-getting-started-with-kubernetes-on-your-windows-laptop-with-minikube-3269b54a226?gi=b4d74acee40c).

Comment: The service term is a little overloaded here. I am not looking at starting a service (e.g. a container, pod, etc.) inside my kubernetes node. What I want it to install kubelet, kubectl, flannel or what ever is necessary as a windows service, so that when I reboot the windows node the Kubernets tools are automatically started.